# Magento 2.3 : Select Random Product id from Product collection

Tags: magento2, product, random

Is there any way to select random product ID from product collection object in magento 2.3

$_productCollection = $this->getProductList($catid);
How can I select random product id from this object

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
$_productCollection = $this
        ->getCategory($catid)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(5);

$_productCollection->getSelect()->orderRand();

$products = $_productCollection->getItems();
```

**hope its work for you.**

Comment: I tried this. And my question is different. After running code given my you if i want random product id how can we do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get random product id from a category.

```
$productIds = array_column($_productCollection->getData(), 'entity_id');
$randomProductId = $productIds[array_rand($productIds)];
echo $randomProductId;
```

Example code in a block file:

```
<?php
namespace Amit\Test\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;

class RandomProductId extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        Category $category,
        Template\Context $context, 
        array $data = array())
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getRandomProductId($categoryId)
    {
        $productCollection = $this->category->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $productIds = array_column($productCollection->getData(), 'entity_id');
        $randomProductId = $productIds[array_rand($productIds)];
        return $randomProductId;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx i am getting random product id. but on page refresh i am agian getting the same id. why so? i want the random id should be changed on every page refresh. Any idea about this?

Comment: any idea about the Ajax post call?

Comment: Maybe the page is cached. You can use the same code in a controller file and call using ajax as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220376/how-i-get-ajax-response-from-controller-in-magento-2

Comment: any example in AJAX for displaying products?

Comment: I believe it should be a new question.